# UK Visa : Maintenance requirement of Family member of a Tier 2 Migrant

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, family, dependent-visa

Me and my wife (both India citizen) are planning to migrate to Belfast. I will be migrating under tire 2 skilled migration Visa, the employer in Belfast will provide me the required sponsorship certificate citing that they will bear £945 for me as the maintenance requirement.

My wife is planning to apply as family member of a Tier 2 Migrant at the same time with me. The offical [document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791595/SWS_Dependant_Guidance_03-2019.pdf) from Visa website suggests that she should

> "having savings of £630 which must have been held for at least three months prior to the date of application" [Point number 80 in the document]

It is also stated that

> "If you apply at the same time as the main applicant, you are only required to provide evidence that you meet the maintenance requirement when the Tier 2 Migrant is also required to meet the maintenance requirement" [Point number 82 in the document]

I am little confused what is meant here. So I would like to know if my wife can show a savings of £630 but NOT necessarily for 3 months, will that be enough for the Visa application?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.